# error when running bazel test of magenta

Tags: tensorflow, magenta

My server is Ubuntu 14.04 CPU 
After installing magenta, I run the 
     bazel test magenta/... ,
 and it gives me this error:

ERROR: /home/jcc/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jcc/ed5599de3378c6e0a5a71ebe1650713e/external/protobuf/protobuf.bzl:91:19: name 'HOST_CFG' is not defined.

ERROR: package contains errors: magenta/protobuf.
ERROR: error loading package 'magenta/protobuf': Extension 'protobuf.bzl' has errors.

INFO: Elapsed time: 0.274s

ERROR: Couldn't start the build. Unable to run tests.

Any advice?

Comment: Hi numberjcc, did you manage to resolve this issue?